# Simple practice sheet for learning Piano

Tags: digital-piano

I am a learner of electronic Piano. I want to know where I can download simple music sheets that helps me to practice my fingures in pressing the keys. It need not be a complete music, but simple exercise sheet. Basically I want to practice pressing the right keys by looking at the music sheet.

Comment: By reading the help centre, you'll find that this sort of question is not a good fit on this site. There are many starter books with graded pieces to practise sight reading available.

Comment: I am a little surprised to learn that this question has been put on hold. First of all this question does not relate to any instrument, so there is no question of this being off-topic. I only sought help from experts for sheet music.

Comment: Basically it's a 'shopping recommendation' question, which is broadly off-topic right across Stack Exchange, as there can be no 'correct' answer, merely a series of equally-valid opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a link to 240 piano exercises for technique purposes, free of charge: https://www.hanon-online.com/

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.

Comment: @victor Resnov: The link that you have posted has helped me. This is what I had been looking for.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't realize that at the time. How can I tell if another question I see is off-topic?

Comment: The specifics are in the Help pages, but generally you just get a feel for it after a time.